Elementary analytic definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$
I'd found a pretty definition of the exponential function (in real analysis):

Theorem (without proof): There exists only one function $\exp:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $\exp'=\exp$ and $\exp(0)=1$.

Then I define $e=\exp(1)$ and for some $a\in\Bbb R$ we have that if for $x\in\Bbb R$,
$$f(x)=\frac{\exp(x+a)}{\exp a}$$
then (assuming the chain rule),
$$f'(x)=\frac{\exp'(x+a)}{\exp a}=\frac{\exp(x+a)}{\exp a}=f(x)$$
Furthermore,
$$f(0)=\frac{\exp a}{\exp a}=1$$
So $f(x)=\exp x$ and then $\exp(x+a)=\exp x\exp a$. So far so good! Now, it is very easy to prove the existence of $\ln$, $\exp>0$ etc.
The question
To introduce trigonometic functions, I've tried

There exists (without proof) only one function $\sin:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$
such that:

$\sin(0)=0$
$\sin'(0)=1$
$\sin''+\sin=0$


I have tried to prove that $\sin(x+a)=\sin a\sin' x+\sin'a\sin x$ using only those properties.
I can't use series or complex analysis.
I can use Leibniz rule and chain rule.

If $g(x)=\sin(x+a)-\sin(a)\sin'(x)-\sin'(a)\sin(x)$, then\begin{align}g'(x)&=\sin'(x+a)-\sin(a)\sin''(x)-\sin'(a)\sin'(x)\\&=\sin'(x+a)+\sin(a)\sin(x)-\sin'(a)\sin'(x),\end{align}and therefore\begin{align}g''(x)&=\sin''(x+a)+\sin(a)\sin'(x)-\sin'(a)\sin''(x)\\&=-\sin(x+a)+\sin(a)\sin'(x)+\sin'(a)\sin(x)\\&=-g(x).\end{align}In other words, you always have $g(x)+g''(x)=0$. Therefore, you always have $g(x)g'(x)+g'(x)g''(x)=0$, which means that $\left(g^2(x)+g'^2(x)\right)'=0$. So, $g^2+g'^2$ is a constant function. But $g(0)=\sin(a)-\sin(a)=0$, and $g'(0)=\sin'(a)-\sin'(a)=0$. So, $g^2+g'^2$ is the null function. In particular, $g$ is the null function. In other words, you always have$$\sin(x+a)=\sin(a)\sin'(x)-\sin'(a)\sin(x)..$$

So beautiful! Thank you very much

I'm glad I could help.

Related, if not duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1750563/42969
